# Как с помощью .css настроить внешний вид таблицы TableView?

Tags: css, javafx, tableview

Пытаюсь с помощью .css настроить внешний вид таблицы TableView, а именно, чтоб выделенная строка светилась голубым, а выделенная ячейка в ней синим(цвета значения не имеют).

Использую css:

```
.table-row-cell:selected {
-fx-background-color: blue; 
}

.table-cell:selected{
-fx-background-color: green; 
}
```

При установке свойства для таблицы

```
getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true); //красит только ячейку
getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(false); //красит всю строку.
```

Comment: А если сделать оттенок для  .table-row-cell:focused?

Comment: Вы свои классы не определяли? Посмотрите по этой ссылке, я думаю вам поможет она http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tableview

Comment: .table-row-cell:focused - заливает всю строку